# How to convert a .tif file in which transparency is implicit into tiles with transparency?

Tags: transparency-opacity

Reproducible example with QGIS:

Download this file: https://github.com/npct/pct-lsoa-vis/releases/download/0.0.1/dutch_slc-10m-merge2-test.tif

Open it in QGIS, open the Layer Properties Window, and untick No Data Value.

It looks like this (note unwanted red patches):

[image]

What I would like is for it to be transparent, even when the transparency tick box is unticked, and an output that is something like this (see code below that creates this updated 'fixed' file - but the problem is that this is not geo-referenced): https://github.com/npct/pct-lsoa-vis/releases/download/0.0.1/test-fixed.tif

**Note: I tried to solve this using this post but it the input data types are different, this question is fully reproducible, and the 'correct' answer does not work: [How do I convince gdal2tiles to output pngs with transparency?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154387/how-do-i-convince-gdal2tiles-to-output-pngs-with-transparency) hence creating a new question.**

Is there a way to do this with GDAL? This was what I did (with the tiling command produced by QGIS):

```
gdalwarp -dstalpha -srcnodata "255 0 0" -co "ALPHA=YES" dutch_slc-10m-merge2-test.tif "raster_w-alpha.tif"
gdal2tiles -p mercator -z 5-14 -w all -r average -a 0.0 raster_w-alpha.tif output
```

Which I think is almost there, but looses the colours:

[image]

I've also tried these commands in GDAL 2.4, but none worked:

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata "255,0,0" -dstnodata "0,0,0" -wo INIT_DEST="255,255,255,0"  dutch_slc-10m-merge2-test.tif dutch_slc-10m-merge2-test4.tif
gdal_translate -a_nodata "0,0,0" dutch_slc-10m-merge2-test.tif dutch_slc-10m-merge2-test2.tif 
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "255 0 0" outfile.vrt dutch_slc-10m-merge2-test.tif 
gdal_translate outfile.vrt final.tif
```

Reproducible example showing a way to do what I'm after with `magick`:

```r
u = "https://github.com/npct/pct-lsoa-vis/releases/download/0.0.1/dutch_slc-10m-merge2-test.tif"
download.file(url = u, destfile = "test.tif")
remotes::install_cran("magick")
#> Skipping install of 'magick' from a cran remote, the SHA1 (2.0) has not changed since last install.
#>   Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.7.4
#> Enabled features: fontconfig, freetype, fftw, lcms, pango, x11
#> Disabled features: cairo, ghostscript, rsvg, webp
i = image_read("test.tif")
i
```

[image]

```r
i_fixed = image_transparent(image = i, color = "red")
i_fixed
```

[image]

```r
image_write(i_fixed, "test-fixed.tif")



devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
#>  os       Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS          
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language en_GB:en                    
#>  collate  en_GB.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_GB.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/London               
#>  date     2019-02-28                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version    date       lib source                         
#>  assertthat    0.2.0      2017-04-11 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  backports     1.1.3      2018-12-14 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  callr         3.1.1      2018-12-21 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  cli           1.0.1      2018-09-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  crayon        1.3.4      2017-09-16 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  curl          3.3        2019-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  desc          1.2.0      2018-05-01 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  devtools      2.0.1      2018-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  digest        0.6.18     2018-10-10 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  evaluate      0.13       2019-02-12 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  fs            1.2.6      2018-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  glue          1.3.0.9000 2019-01-28 [1] Github (tidyverse/glue@8188cea)
#>  highr         0.7        2018-06-09 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  htmltools     0.3.6      2017-04-28 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  httr          1.4.0      2018-12-11 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  knitr         1.21       2018-12-10 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  magick      * 2.0        2018-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  magrittr      1.5        2014-11-22 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  memoise       1.1.0      2017-04-21 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  mime          0.6        2018-10-05 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  pkgbuild      1.0.2      2018-10-16 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  pkgload       1.0.2      2018-10-29 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  png           0.1-7      2013-12-03 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  prettyunits   1.0.2      2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  processx      3.2.1      2018-12-05 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  ps            1.3.0      2018-12-21 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  R6            2.4.0      2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  Rcpp          1.0.0      2018-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  remotes       2.0.2      2018-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  rlang         0.3.1      2019-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  rmarkdown     1.11       2018-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2      2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  stringi       1.3.1      2019-02-13 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  stringr       1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)                 
#>  testthat      2.0.1      2018-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  usethis       1.4.0      2018-08-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#>  withr         2.1.2      2018-03-15 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  xfun          0.5.1      2019-02-23 [1] Github (yihui/xfun@d547831)    
#>  xml2          1.2.0      2018-01-24 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.0)                 
#>  yaml          2.2.0      2018-07-25 [3] CRAN (R 3.5.1)                 
#> 
#> [1] /home/robin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5
#> [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#> [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#> [4] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a mask band or alpha channel - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24822/2856

Comment: Not sure but think I may have found an answer. Will post below, not sure if that's the best way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The answer below applies to the edited question

You need to make your NoData value consistent across the bands

```
gdalbuildvrt -ot byte -srcnodata "255 0 0" -vrtnodata "0 0 0" output.vrt input.tif
```

Then convert to Byte datatype (as gdal2tiles.py doesn't seem to handle Float32 very well)

```
gdal_translate -ot Byte output.vrt output2.vrt
```

Then tile it:

```
gdal2tiles.py -p mercator -z 5-14 -w all -r average -a 255 output2.vrt output
```

[image]

---

## The answer below is correct for the original unedited question which has since changed

You can use an [alpha channel/mask band](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24822/2856):

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata "255 0 0"  -dstalpha  -co "ALPHA=YES" input.tif output.tif
```

Comment: Thanks - tried that also but from a tiling perspective it still does not show as transparent - the same as my answer.

Comment: @RobinLovelace, you asked about creating a tiff not creating tiles. PNG can store an alpha channel, so perhaps ask a new question with details about how you are creating the tiles.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, I've updated the question accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

Update, based on another SO question I tried this, and think it may have solved it:

```
gdalwarp -dstalpha -srcnodata "255 0 0" -co "ALPHA=YES" dutch_slc-10m-merge2-test.tif "raster_w-alpha.tif"
```

[How to calculate a new raster based on nodata values from original raster, in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24777/how-to-calculate-a-new-raster-based-on-nodata-values-from-original-raster-in-qg?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The problem with this approach: when I tile it, the tiles are still are *still* not transparent.

Here is the result, containing `leaflet.html` which shows that the transparency still is not there: https://github.com/mem48/pct-raster-tests/files/2914883/raster_w-alpha.zip

Screenshot of the tiled result in that zip file generated by the above command (and the command suggested by another post):

[image]